# Fluent NHibernate Automapper maps Enum to nvarchar(255) and not int?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Why are enums mapped as strings and not as ints when using automapper in Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to Mikael Henriksson at the [fluent-nhibernate mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/45875dea3b5555a3) i found the answer:

```
public class EnumConvention :
    IPropertyConvention,
    IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    #region IPropertyConvention Members

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomType(instance.Property.PropertyType);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IPropertyConventionAcceptance Members

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum);
    }

    #endregion

}
```